# No Error, but still Error in Autowiring in Spring Core

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

```
 In class Heart have Following variable


public class Heart {
private int noofheart;
private String nameOfAnimal;
```

this is my bean.xml

```
<bean id="octopose" class="com.spring.auto.Heart">
        <property name="nameOfAnimal" value="octopos"></property>
    <property name="noofheart" value="3"></property>
</bean>
```

actually proerty tag is not working properly,it gives Error of getter and Setter while   i am using annotation as follow:

```
@Autowired
private Heart heart;
```

and not using getter and setter however I also Checked with getter and Setter but still not working error are as follow:
Invalid property 'nameOfAnimal' of bean class [com.spring.auto.Heart]: Bean property 'nameOfAnimal' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the statement, not just prepare it:

```java
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Additionally, as a practice, you should not assume the connect auto-commits, but explicitly commit yourself:

```
conn.commit();
```

Comment: thanks but it give me error :-org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Table"
  Position: 13

Comment: @SantoshChouhan Your SQL syntax is wrong. Remove the word "table" from there and it should be OK.

Comment: thank once again sir,but still facing problem,showing org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.employee" does not exist,however it exist under public schema in my_first_databse

Comment: REATE TABLE public."Employee"
(
    "Eid" character varying(40)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    firstname character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastname character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(40)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "Employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Eid")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Employee"
    OWNER to postgres;

Comment: Dear Sir i have also add screenshot of pgadmin in question ,please help me I stucked in this problem since arrival of corona in india

Comment: Your error is the use of double quotes (") in the create table, but not on the insert statement. Postgres converts all object names to lower case except when enclosed in double quotes. But all references then must also use double quotes. So you created table "Employee" but referenced table employee. Those are NOT the same. Solution: do not use double quotes for object names.